# SQL LOADER ERROR ON FIRST RECORD

Tags: oracle

I am trying to load data from a file into a table in Oracle but i am receiving a error only on first record ,second record is getting Inserted.
Record 1: Rejected - Error on table Ing_Details, column INGREDIENT_ID.
        ORA-01722: invalid number

This is the Control file

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE  'C:\Users\Appdata\Desktop\SQl Loader\ing1.txt'
BADFILE 'C:\Users\Appdata\Desktop\SQl Loader\bad_orders.txt'
INTO TABLE Ing_Details 
FIELDS
TERMINATED BY "\t"
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
     TRAILING NULLCOLS
( 
INGREDIENT_ID NULLIF INGREDIENT_TYPE_ID=BLANKS,
INGREDIENT_TYPE_ID NULLIF INGREDIENT_TYPE_ID=BLANKS,
Status NULLIF Status=BLANKS,
Organic NULLIF Organic=BLANKS
)
```

Table Structure

```
Ingredient_ID              NUMBER NOT NULL,
   Ingredient_Type_ID         NUMBER NOT NULL,
   Status                     NUMBER (10) NOT NULL,
   Organic                    NUMBER (10) NOT NULL
```

log File:

```
SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Mon Jul 11 12:25:59 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Control File:   C:\Users\Appdata\Desktop\ingredient2.ctl
Data File:      C:\Users\Appdata\Desktop\SQl Loader\ing1.csv
  Bad File:     C:\Users\Appdata\Desktop\SQl Loader\bad_orders.txt
  Discard File:  none specified

 (Allow all discards)

Number to load: ALL
Number to skip: 0
Errors allowed: 50
Bind array:     64 rows, maximum of 256000 bytes
Continuation:    none specified
Path used:      Conventional

    Table Ing_Details, loaded from every logical record.
    Insert option in effect for this table: INSERT
    TRAILING NULLCOLS option in effect

       Column Name                  Position   Len  Term Encl Datatype
    ------------------------------ ---------- ----- ---- ---- ---------------------
    INGREDIENT_ID                       FIRST     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            
        NULL if INGREDIENT_TYPE_ID = BLANKS
    INGREDIENT_TYPE_ID                   NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            
        NULL if INGREDIENT_TYPE_ID = BLANKS
    STATUS                               NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            
        NULL if STATUS = BLANKS
    ORGANIC                              NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            
        NULL if ORGANIC = BLANKS

    Record 1: Rejected - Error on table Ing_Details, column INGREDIENT_ID.
    ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Comment: flatfile data 
1 2 1 0
2 2 1 0

Comment: Just look at your data. I would guess that the first column of the first row is not a valid number, possibly you've got a header row? If you do have a header row use `skip 1`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Ben.I do not have header row.when i left first row as blank data got inserted into Table.
 
 1 2 0 0
 2 2 1 0

Comment: @pramod did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

Check the encoding on the data file.  SQLLDR seems to have issues with BOM'd UTF-8 files, as it adds 3 bytes to the beginning of the file ([UTF-8 vs UTF-8 w/o BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2223976/2795943)).  These bytes are included in the first defined field (in accordance with the `.ctl` file), which Oracle can then not convert into a `NUMBER`.  By adding and skipping a blank header row in the data file, you have essentially nullified the effect of the 3 extra bytes.

An easy way to check encoding on the file is to open the file in Notepad++ and open the Encoding menu item.

[image: Notepad++]

If necessary, select `Encode UTF-8 without BOM` to change the file encoding.